# How to tell search engines NOT to look at this specific link?

Tags: seo

Suppose I have a link in the page `<a href="/mymessages">My Messages</a>`, which on click will display an alert message "You must login to access my messages".

May be it's better to just *not* display this link when user is not logged in, but I want "My Messages" to be visible even if user is not logged in.

I think this link is user-friendly, but for search engines they will get redirected to login page, which I think is.. bad for SEO? or is it fine?

I thought of keeping `My Messages` displayed as normal text (not as a link), then wrap it with a link tag by using javascript/jquery, is this solution good or bad? other ideas please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of keeping the URL from affecting your rank is setting the `rel` attribute of your link:

```
<a href="/mymessages" rel="nofollow">My Messages</a>
```

Another option is `robots.txt`, that way you can disallow the bots from the URL entirely.

Comment: Best answer and best reason :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to create a robots.txt file and write:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /mymessages
```

This will keep SEO bots out of that folder

Answer (score 4):

Use a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file to tell search engines which pages they should not index.

Using [nofollow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) to block access to a page is erroneous - this is not what nofollow is for. This attribute was designed to allow to you place a link in page without conferring any weight or endorsement of the link. In other words, it's not a link that search engines should regard as significant for page-ranking algorithms. It does not mean "do not index this page" - just "don't follow *this particular link* to that page"

Here's what [Google have to say about nofollow](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=96569)

> ...However, the target pages may still appear in our index if other
>   sites link to them without using nofollow or if the URLs are submitted
>   to Google in a Sitemap. Also, it's important to note that other search
>   engines may handle nofollow in slightly different ways.

Comment: Nice explanation! Do you advise me to use robots.txt only, or use both robots.txt AND "nofollow" rel attribute?

Comment: He does not really want to keep search bots from a certain URL, he just wants to be sure the URL does not affect his ranking. In that case I think that using `nofollow` is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use robots.txt to exclude /mymessages. This will also prevent engines which have already visited /mymessages from visiting it again.

Alternatively, add the following to the top of the /mymessages script:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to tell search engines, not to follow a particular link , then use rel="nofollow".
It is a way to tell search engines and bots that don't follow this link.
Now,google will not crawl that link and does not transfer PageRank or anchor text across this link.